# Ant, Tomcat Build Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/buf/B2CConverter

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, spring-mvc

Tomcat Version: 7.0.20

I am attempting to work my way through the following *Spring MVC* tutorial:
http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html

In this tutorial, an *ant* build script is setup to deploy to tomcat using the manager.  However, I run into some problems when I try to run any of the tomcat tasks.

First off, in the tutorial, they still use `org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask` which is deprecated, so I changed to `org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask`.

Now the problem is that when trying to run the Tomcat tasks I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/buf/B2CConverter
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Base64.encode(Base64.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask.execute(ReloadTask.java:45)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 21 more
```

So I Googled around a bit and found some information stating that `tomcat-utils.jar` should be in the class path so I added that into the fileset with the catalina-ant.jar but apparently the `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter` class is not in there.

So next I started probing the jars with `jar -tf` to find out if any contained the class.  I found out that `tomcat-coyote.jar` had the class.  Even with including this in the fileset, the problem is not resolved.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Definitive reference on configuring Ant and Tomcat 7:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing%20Manager%20Commands%20With%20Ant

Answer (score 29):

I got this working by changing the classpath to

```
<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
    <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs --> 
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
        <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
        <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
                <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Comment: I found a similar case here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/551052/Spring/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-org-apache however the solution is the same as provided here and does not work for me.  If it means anything, I'm on Mac OS X.

Comment: I had also problems with making this work, the final missing step was: Remove the catalina-ant.jar from $ANT_HOME/lib, if you copied it there during the previous trial-error session.

Answer (score 15):

Like Jason, I tried Aidan's answer and it did not work. With TomCat 7 the manager interface has changed a little. Instead of using /manager/list in the URL you have to use /manager/text/list. So I changed the list task in build.xml to the following:

```
<target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
    <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}/text"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
</target>
```

I also had to add the "manager-script" role to my admin user so that it would have the proper privileges for this operation:

```
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

Comment: That is good advice for Tomcat 7 setup, but I don't think its relevant to the solution to this problem.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: I too am trying to get this spring MVC tutorial working, this tip did get the build tasks to work for me in conjunction with aidan's configuration above.  However I'd recommend fixing the tomcat manager url for all the ant tasks by editing the build.properties file and setting the tomcat.manager.url to include the /text.

Comment: Don't forget to restart the tomcat server!

Answer (score 12):

I found the same error when following the same tutorial.
I had to make 3 changes so that the targets run correctly.

First, change the build.xml "list" target to add the /text above mentioned:

```
<target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
    <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}/text"
          username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
          password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
</target>
```

Second, change the catalina ant classpath:

```
<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/lib">
        <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
        <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
        <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
        <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

And finally, add this to the tomcat-users.xml file:

```
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui,tomcat,manager-script"/>
```

And then it worked for me =)

Comment: Just tested with 7.0.33 and it works when all the three steps are added.

Comment: @Jason Turner This is the correct answer I am also running Mac OS and doing what Neets suggested fixes the problem. Make sure you are changing the Catalina Classpath and not the Master Classpath

Answer (score 3):

This seemed to work for me (Tomcat 7.0.21, OS X):

```
<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
  <fileset dir="${tomcat_dir}/lib">
    <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
    <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
    <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
  </fileset>
  <fileset dir="${tomcat_dir}/bin">
    <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>
<taskdef name="deploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
<taskdef name="undeploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.UndeployTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
<taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Basically the same as Aidan's though.  I tried it anyways and got the same result.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get all the ant commands to work the manager url can be changed in the build.properties file instead of changing the url when defining the "list" target in the build.xml file.

```
tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager/text
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answer work for me. Instead I copied TOMCAT_HOME/lib/catalina-ant.jar, TOMCAT_HOME/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar, TOMCAT_HOME/lib/tomcat-util.jar and TOMCAT_HOME/bin/tomcat-juli.jar to the ANT_HOME/lib directory.

It seems like the classpathref doesn't include these files properly.

Comment: You probably had _catalina-ant.jar_ in **ANT_HOME/lib**. Try removing it from this location, and then try to deploy again with classpath set as in one of the previous answers...

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me was adding the four jar files to the build path

Run -> run configuration -> choose you program, select Classpath tab on the right, click User Entries, then add external 4 jars from the tomcat directory

After this my build.xml runs like before

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why is this happening, but here's a workaround:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/553582/Tomcat/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-org-apache

I'm looking for the solution, once I get it I will try not to forget to post it in here.

I use opensuse.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Mac OS X. This worked for me:

```
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Tomcat tasks - remove these if you don't have Tomcat installed -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->

    <path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
        <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
        <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
        <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
            <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
        <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
        <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
        <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
      </fileset>        
    </path>
```

Answer (score 0):

I new to Spring or even first use to tomcat, i'm just trying add classpath  to subsection tomcat task in build.xml (in every tomcat task) and i dont why, but its works.

```
<taskdef name="deploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
    <classpath>
        <path location="${appserver.home}/lib/catalina-ant.jar"/>
        <path location="${appserver.home}/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
        <path location="${appserver.home}/lib/tomcat-util.jar"/>
        <path location="${appserver.home}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing above changes and running "ant list", I got error as,
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..../manager/text/list".
It was resolved by starting tomcat from its installation directory and not using eclipse to start it.
After starting tomcat, first try "localhost:8080" in the browser. This should display tomcats page. Then try running "ant list". It works and above issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a minor modification to the previous answers.

Configuring a user to have both manager-gui and manager-script roles is strongly discouraged in the Tomcat 7 documentation [1](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access).  It can leave your site open to CSRF attacks.

Defining separate users with different passwords for each role would be safer:

```
<role rolename="manager-"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin-gui" password="s3cret1" roles="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin-script" password="s3cret2" roles="manager-script"/>
```

In general, you only need to memorize the user name and password for the GUI user, so it's no burden to have a safer configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Three Things-

- If using Tomcat 7.x 
  Change fileset for catalina-ant-classpath

  ```
  <path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
      <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
      <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
      <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
          <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
      <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
      <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
      <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  ```
- change the user in tomcat-users.xml to give user permission as manager-script
- Change tomcat.manager.url property to `http://localhost:8080/manager/text`

Answer (score 0):

Three Things-

If using Tomcat 7.x Change fileset for catalina-ant-classpath

```
    <path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
    <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
    <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
  </fileset>
  <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
    <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
  </fileset> 
</path>
```

change the user in tomcat-users.xml to give user permission as manager-script

Change tomcat.manager.url property to `http://localhost:8080/manager/text`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `catalina-ant.jar` `tomcat-coyote.jar` and `tomcat-util.jar` from `tomcat_home/lib/` directory to `ant_home/lib/` directory